# Android make a http request and ignore response

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I'm developing a program that sends some Logs to a database.
As logs, the main idea is to save as much information as it can, I want to avoid the part if the server where I store logs is down. What I'm trying to do is to make an http request and totally ignore server response, it doesn't matter if is online or offline. What I'm done so far is to set a timeout to my request but that doesn't resolve my problem. Here is my code:

```
public synchronized void LOG_sendERROR(String token, String channelnumber, String type)
{       
    HttpResponse response = null;

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeout = 3000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,timeout);
    int timeoutsocket = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutsocket);
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


    try
    {                   
        if (ep.getString("username", "").length() == 0)
            return ;

        String url = Server.Log_Server + "/LOG_CHANNEL_LOGS.aspx?params=1";

        log.i("LOGS", url);

        HttpGet c = new HttpGet(url);

        response = httpclient.execute(c); 

        return ;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        try
        {
            if (response != null)
                response.getEntity().consumeContent();
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {

        }

        return ;
    }
}
```

If server is down my application stuck for 3 seconds. I want to send the logs, it doesn't matter for the client application to know whether the server saved the logs the client just send. How can I make a http request and ignore response?

Comment: try to use Asynctask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i tried many methods, the best way is to execute as a parallel task. In this way client wont ignore the response of the server but at least the application will be running normaly.

```
private Runnable LOG_CHANNEL_LOGS = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        new LOG_CHANNEL_LOGS().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);   
    }
};
```